# Rotate Plotly Line Markers

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I am trying to plot a timeline of events with Plotly, and I have the following example code:

```
res = {
    "First event": 5,
    "Second event": 6,
    "Third event": 30
}

names, dates = zip(*res.items())

trace = go.Scatter(
    x=dates, y=[0] * len(names), text=names, mode='lines+markers+text', 
    marker=dict(
        symbol="hexagon-dot",
        size=10,
    )
)

layout = go.Layout()
fig = go.Figure(layout=layout, data=[trace])
iplot(fig)
```

I get the following result:
[image]

What I would like to do is rotate the marker text so that the markers do not overlap. Can this be done?

Comment: You would need to use `annotations` but there is no out of the box feature: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1210

Comment: Alas. Thank you.